# PhotoShop Curved Lines

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Okay, I am trying to make a curved line in PhotoShop. Probably sounds pretty Easy.

Just playing around, I managed to make this: I don't remember how I did it though. I know I used the line tool.

See how it fades out in the middle? I don't like that. I want it to be solid all the way through. What is a better way to come up with a line such as this in Photoshop

[image]

Comment: It's very hard to see what's going on there, is there anyway you can post a full resolution version? Even if it was only a small portion of the middle section.

Answer (score 1):

1) Select the `Pen Tool (P)` from your `Tools` window.

2) In the `Options` window, set the `tool mode` dropdown to `Shape`, set the `Fill` dropdown to `No Color`, and choose a `Stroke Color` and `Stroke Width`.

3) Click-drag on your canvas to draw points on a [Bezier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bezier_curve).

4) Use the `Direct Selection Tool (Shift A)` to make adjustments. Click curve handles to adjust curve angles. Command-click points to move points.

Comment: @user2948950 This should solve your issue, just  comment if you need further clarification. Welcome to GD.SE!